# ArrayOutOfBounds error when i run a for-each-loop in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a code that looks through a given array list named values and returns True if found i've gotten it to work for a for-loop and a while-loop but can't figure out how to get the for-each loop to work. Here is what i have that'd giving me the error.

**EDIT: the error says "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:642327, Size 30590 (in java.util.ArrayList)**

```
public String twoforEachFoundIt(ArrayList<Integer> values, int number){
    for(int i:values) {
         if (values.get(i)== number){
            return "True";
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the down votes. It makes me feel very welcome. 

I'm new to programming and I did try to look stuff up for myself but since I'm new none of the stuff I found made sense to me.

But thank you to the people who helped answer my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're iterating over the list, you're putting the **contents** of the list into `i`. Then you're using that `i` as an **index** into the list.

You can just compare `i` directly:

```
if (i == number)
    return "True";
```

As a note, you may want to change your function to return a `boolean` rather than a `String`...

Comment: Thank you. We didn't really go over for-each in class and I couldn't make heads or tails of anything I found explaining them online.

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'i' has the value of the element and not the index. Correct way is :

```
if ( i== number)
return "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `foreach` **is iterating over the elements** of the `ArrayList values`, you must compare `number` with the actual element:

```
for (int i : values) {
     if (i == number){
        return "True";
    }
}
```

If you want to use indexes, use a simple `for`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
     if (values.get(i) == number){
        return "True";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already did it with a for-loop and a while-loop. I was trying to do it with all three types of loops.

Answer (score 0):

The `foraech` give you the content of the array `values` and not the index. You can simply compare:

```
if (i == number){
    return "True";
}
```