# does index start at 1 for enhanced for loop

Tags: foreach

I am trying to convert a int array to arraylist and print it, i can print it using for loop, but i need to use enhanced for loop, for better understanding.

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            l.add(a[i]);
            //System.out.println(l.get(i));
        }
        
        for(int i : l) {
            System.out.println(i);
            l.get(i);
        }
}
```

}

output :
1
2
3
4
5
6
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433) at Test.main(Test.java:18)`

Why indexing is not starting at 0 here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayOutOfBounds error when i run a for-each-loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974748/arrayoutofbounds-error-when-i-run-a-for-each-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For loops** are appropriate loops when you know exactly how many times iteration you want in statements within the loop.
For loop iterates a statement or a block of statements repeatedly until a specified expression evaluates to false.
In the case of for the variable of the loop is always be int only.

**For-each loop** is used to iterate through the items in object collections, List generic collections, or array list collections.
In the case of Foreach the variable of the loop while being the same as the type of values under the array.

**For each loop do not keep track of the index. So we can not obtain array index using For-Each loop**

In your code in **for each loop**, you get object by index like  **l.get(i);**

l is the Arraylist type and it stores the value from 0 index. Also, your ArrayList contains an integer value. When you reach at 6th object at that time you are accessing **l.get(6)** at that time IndexOutOfBoundsException throws.

So, remove **l.get(i);** from your program.